# clearInterval()-Method in JavaScript - How does it exactly work?

Tags: javascript

I have a script which waits for specific DOM-Elements to be loaded and when loaded it appends another HTML-Element:

```
var checkExistVOID = setInterval(function() {
   if( $('#voidDocumentsAwaitingMyApproval').length && $('#voidDocumentsAwaitingMySignature').length ) {
    $("#loadingBarPolarion1").hide(); 
    $('<span style="font-size: 14px;"><i style="color: lightgreen; padding-right: 10px;" class="fas fa-check"></i>Currently no Document Actions required</span>').appendTo('#voidDocumentsAwaitingMyApproval');  
    clearInterval(checkExistVOID); 
 }
}, 500);
```

My aim was to only trigger this function once, that's why I used the Method:

```
clearInterval()
```

It seems to work fine at first glance, but if the site where the page is executed stays opened for about ~30 minutes without any user action, the `append`-function is all of a sudden executed every `500 ms` on a loop:

[image]

I was wondering, what can be the issue of this? Is it possible that `clearInterval()` suddenly isn't "stored anymore"?

Can you suggest me what to change in my function in order to not run into this problem?

I was thinking about an additional check for the already exiting `<span>`-ELement and use that in the `if`-Function, but I guess that's not a professional solution :)

Comment: *"My aim was to only trigger this function once"*: use `setTimeout()` instead. You're conditionally clearing the interval. If the condition is not met, the interval will not be cleared.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: Thank you very much for your comment. So I only need to change `setInterval()` to `setTimeout()` and that's the magic?

Comment: Use `setTimeout()`

Comment: Yup. And no need to assign it to a variable, and no need to clear it.

Comment: Thats all the magic yea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're conditionally clearing the interval. If the condition is not met, the interval will not be cleared.

> My aim was to only trigger this function once

You should use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) instead.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try and come back to you then :)